# How do you like my writing?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Robots have iron noses.
>   Operative extremists display dystopian intent.
>   Extra apex predators emphasize dominant attitude.
>   Lambada teacher oversees Nightwish aficionado.
>   Reorganize big ordinary room boxes.
>   I tried the extreme ride level.
>   One western elite actor sang extraordinarily.

How do you like my writing so far? Looking for a two-word answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Step 1 :

> Taking the first letter of each word in the text yields : RHINO EDDIE APE DALTON ARBOR BITTER LOW EASE

Step 2 :

> Taking the last letter of each word in the text yields : SENSE SYNTAX SET EAR SHOE GYM SIDE EEL ENERGY

Step 3 :

> Take the first letter of each word generated in step 1 : READABLE

Step 4 :

> Take the last letter of each word generated in step 2 : EXTREMELY

Thus, your writing is

> EXTREMELY READABLE

Credits to [Soltius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80579/how-do-you-like-my-writing/80580#80580) for finding step 1.
Also credits to NudgeNudge and M Oehm for finding out steps 2 and 3 were possible

Comment: And credits to @MOehm for finding step 3 ;)

Comment: Thanks. The final answer answers the question, of course, but it also describes the whole puzzle cryptically.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer :

> Reading the last letter of every word, we get SENSESYNTAXSETEARSHOEGYMSIDEEELDENERGY, where some words seem to appear : SENSE, SYNTAX, ENERGY.

Comment: Seems like you can do the same with rot13(gur svefg yrggre va rirel jbeq)

Comment: One way to interpret your result would be: (rot13) FRAFR FLAGNK FRG RNE FUBR TLZ FVQR RRY RARETL

Comment: you appear to have an extra letter between the last two words, Soltius

Comment: And it seems that (lbh pna qb vg gjvpr)..